# div not updating its 100% height when scrolling down page?

Tags: css, position, height

Ive got a div thats set to `height:100%;` and positioned used `position:absolute` it all works fine but when the content of the div causes it to go off the page and forces it to scroll, the div does not update its height.

Ive made a jsfiddle showing the problem http://jsfiddle.net/jw8Qc/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `height` property to `auto` or try to use `min-height: auto` and it should works.

**Note:** But with `min-height` property i'm not sure with its compatibility.

Also here is i think problem with `min-height` in `IE` especially in `IE 9`.

**EDIT:**

```
.slide-out {
   position:absolute; 
   top:0; 
   left:155px; 
   width:375px; 
}

.slide-cont {
   background:#000;
   margin:20px;
   height: auto;
}
```

Comment: with height:auto; you lose the background all together, and min-height:100% dosnt change it

Answer (score 0):

Try using min-height:100% instead of height:100%

Answer (score 0):

.slide-out { position:absolute; top:0; left:155px; width:375px; }
.slide-cont { background:#000; margin:20px; height: auto; }

Comment: .slide-out {
   position:absolute; 
   top:0; 
   left:155px; 
   width:375px; 
}

.slide-cont {
   background:#000;
   margin:20px;
   height: auto;
}